# How to make read progressBar smoother react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have function to show reading article progress,my problem is it doesnt go smooth at all how i can remove this lagging effect.On useEffect hook it set procent of all page hight. After that i set width in styled component to that procent. It all working but i cant rid off this lagging and its very annoying.

```
 export const SingleArticle = () => {
   const [readProgress, setReadProgress] = useState(0)

   useEffect(() => {
      const calcReadProgress = () => {
         const { scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement

         const height = scrollHeight - clientHeight

         setReadProgress((document.documentElement.scrollTop / height) * 100)
      }

      window.addEventListener('scroll', calcReadProgress)

      return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', calcReadProgress)
   }, [])

   return (
        <ReadProgressBar progress={readProgress} />
   )
}

type StyledProps = {
   progress: number
}

export const ReadProgressBar = styled.div<StyledProps>`
   width: 100%;
   height: 10px;
   background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.darkBlue};
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 10;
   &::after {
      content: '';
      width: ${({ progress }) => (progress ? `${progress}%` : '0%')};
      height: 10px;
      background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.purple};
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
   }
`
```

Comment: try to add transition property in styled component

Comment: @18jad nope its not it also i have changed  `useEffect` to `useLayoutEffect` doesnt helped